# enable swipe on view controller, but disable within a view in that VC

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController where I have 2 UISwipeGestureRecognizers handling undo and redo (swipe right to undo, swiple left to redo).  Within this VC I also have a UIView that is tracking touch began/moved/ended to change colors on another UIView.  BTW, the undo/redo has to do with the color changes.

The problem I'm running into is that when I'm doing the touch events in the color changer view, they are sometimes interpreted as a swipe and undo/redo are happening.

How can I disable the swipe gestures just for the UIView in question but retain the ability to perform swipes on other areas of the VC?

Answer (score 1):

Make the view controller a delegate of the gesture recognizer, then implement this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    return touch.view != self.mySubviewToExclude;
}
```

Comment: thx. I got all that in there and the delegate method is being called, but the view from the GR is not the color changer subview. I also tried iskindof but no luck. Do i need to implement the GR delegate on the subview for this to work?  Currently the color chooser view has no protocols it implements, just touch began/moved/ended.

Comment: the gestureRecognizer.view ends up being the same value as the self.view where self is the VC. The two swipe gesture recognizers are defined in the VC with swipeRight.delegate=self and swipeLeft.delegate=self.  Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here but so far no luck.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't compare it to self.view.  You must compare it to the view you want to exclude.

Comment: the gestureRecognizer.view never is the value of the color changer view.  it is always the value of self.view

Comment: Oh geez.  My bad.  It's the touch's view we care about.  I'll edit to correct.  Sorry about that.